# Filter coordinates in a given range

Tags: python, bash, coordinates

I've got hundreds of .out files with geographical positions, that I will bulk import into an SQLite database. However, to save time, I will only import the line with geographical coordinates inside some intervals.

The file is like this:

```
value;value;longitude;latitude;value;value
value;value;longitude;latitude;value;value
```

So everything that isn't inside *several* latitude, and longitude intervals should be deleted from the file.

```
for f in *.out
do
for each line in $f:
    if not longitude >= longitude1 and longitude <= longitude2 
    or longitude >= longitude3 and longitude <= longitude4 or
    longitude>=longitude5 and longitude<=4:
         delete line
```

I have included a pseudocode to show some effort, but how would I do this in Bash, awk, python or what ever method is the fastest.

The longitude and latitude is the third and fourth value here. I have 21 latitude intervals, f.ex 69.41 to 70.95 (latitude).

Example input

```
63;543534;34,12;59,43;22,80;654,324;139543;
63;25725;5,11;59,43;22,80;36,00;1391212800;
61;5382189;3,66;60,93;68,00;158,00;1391212800;
43;25977000;10,72;67,51;170,70;168,00;1391212800;
61;2000;4,54;60,00;352,50;352,00;1391212800;
53;2504210;6,96;62,89;289,40;511,00;1391212800;
27;2594800;22,35;70,24;14,50;98,00;1391212800;
61;257900;5,13;60,13;321,10;195,00;1391212800;
31;2598;18,76;69,56;230,20;235,00;1391212800;
63;44000;5,84;59,01;226,90;227,00;1391212800;
61;0;4,96;60,57;125,50;129,00;1391212800;
57;2575000;4,88;61,77;113,00;276,00;1391212800;
34;258500;16,58;69,70;18,20;201,00;1391212800;
243;217000;7,18;65,25;283,00;145,00;1391212800;
243;21900;7,20;64,97;44,80;109,00;1391212800;
243;2190516;2,44;58,20;270,50;121,00;1391212800;
243;22000;1,94;58,39;305,20;130,00;1391212800;
243;231067000;1,87;58,09;12,00;122,00;1391212800;
243;311000150;3,54;61,13;166,30;332,00;1391212800;
243;257282000;7,21;64,97;267,10;112,00;1391212800;
243;232758000;1,77;61,43;333,30;337,00;1391212800;
27;231711000;22,42;70,27;99,20;99,00;1391212800;
68;231770000;10,06;58,74;5,40;10,00;1391212800;
```

Desired output with latitude interval 69.41 to 70.95:

```
27;2594800;22,35;70,24;14,50;98,00;1391212800;
31;2598;18,76;69,56;230,20;235,00;1391212800;
34;258500;16,58;69,70;18,20;201,00;1391212800;
27;231711000;22,42;70,27;99,20;99,00;1391212800;
```

Note that this preferrably should be either written to a new file or overwrite the existing file.

Comment: Some real sample input would be helpful here.

Comment: ...and your assumption that bash would be quicker is probably wrong. In the shell, use awk to do this, otherwise, use python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just have one interval to check, pass them and compare:

```
awk -v lat=5 -v min_lat=69.41 -v max_lat=70.95 '
        BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} 
        {sub(",",".",$lat)} 
        $lat>=min_lat && $lat<=max_lat' file
```

With `lat` I indicate the column of the latitude, since it is changing in your edits. Note also the fields have a comma to separate the decimals, so I am replacing them with a dot.

#### Test

```
$ awk -v lat=5 -v min_lat=69.41 -v max_lat=70.95 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {sub(",",".",$lat)} $lat>=min_lat && $lat<=max_lat' file
27;1;2594800;22,35;70.24;14,50;98,00;1391212800;
31;3;2598;18,76;69.56;230,20;235,00;1391212800;
34;3;258500;16,58;69.70;18,20;201,00;1391212800;
27;1;231711000;22,42;70.27;99,20;99,00;1391212800;
```

---

If you happen to have many min and max values, pass them as a string and slice them, so that you can check against them being in an array:

```
awk -v lat=4 -v min="69.41 70.39" -v max="70.95 70.86" '
       BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"; n=split(min,minlat," "); m=split(max,maxlat," ")} 
       {sub(",",".",$lat); 
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)  {
             if ($lat>=minlat[i] && $lat<=maxlat[i])
               {print; next}
        }
       }' file
```

This reads the intervals into the array `minlat[]` and `maxlat[]` and then compares the latitude with all the pairs `(minlat[1], maxlat[1]), (minlat[2], maxlat[2]), ...`. If one matches, it prints the record and skips to the next one, to prevent printing more than once.

#### Test

```
$ awk -v lat=4 -v min="69.41 70.39" -v max="70.95 70.86" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"; n=split(min,minlat," "); m=split(max,maxlat," ")} {sub(",",".",$lat); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {if ($lat>=minlat[i] && $lat<=maxlat[i]) {print; next}}}' file
27;2594800;22,35;70.24;14,50;98,00;1391212800;
31;2598;18,76;69.56;230,20;235,00;1391212800;
34;258500;16,58;69.70;18,20;201,00;1391212800;
27;231711000;22,42;70.27;99,20;99,00;1391212800;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to indicate several different intervals?

Comment: Check the solution and see how you can pass values through `-v` and then check the interval. This should be fine for little amount of intervals.

Comment: It seems like this ouputs the correct lines to the terminal, instead of saving them to an file. Is it possible to rewrite this to the file as there are millions of lines?

Comment: Thank you once again. When several intervals, you propose to just run the code several times with different intervals? The thought is that latitude should be inside either {interval1,interval2} or {interval2,interval2}... up to {interval21,interval21}

Comment: @bjornasm no, you can say `-v min_lat1=... -v min_lat2=...` etc and then do multiple checks: `($lat>=min_lat1 && $lat<=max_lat1) || ($lat>=min_lat2 && $lat<=max_lat2)`.

Comment: @bjornasm Just to be on safer side don't redirect the output to same file else you will erase your entire file before running the awk script itself.

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry, when i tried several intervals like this: http://pastebin.com/9Eexfurb

I got the following `awk: fatal: cannot open file `-v' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @bjornasm You'd be better off just passing in a string with all the coords in, and then splitting it in awk. That way you could also use a loop instead of thousands of `||`

Comment: @User112638726 Thank you, do you have a suggestion on how this would look like? This is my first encounter with awk

Comment: @bjornasm see my update. For this amount of items, you pass them with a string.

Comment: You only need the `m` or the `n` assuming that there will be the same number of mins and maxs. As you never actually use `m`

Comment: @User112638726 it can be useful to check if the given input is valid or not (`if n!=m {exit}` or something like this).

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah could do.

Comment: @fedorqui Just a quick comment, as you see I have trailing ; - could I strip these in the same script in a easy way, so that the final outfile doesn't have these trailing ;

Comment: @bjornasm You can maybe reduce the number of fields in 1 by saying `NF--`. Place it like... `sub(",",".",$lat); NF--;`.

Comment: @fedorqui Hello, the sub(",",".",$lat); only changes the comma up to lat, is it possible to do this for all commas instead?

Comment: @bjornasm this is not how it works: you have to do some kind of effort to understand how `awk` functions. Check it out, test it and, eventually, ask another question. I have gone quite far with updating my answer after your multiple changes in requirements.

Comment: @bjornasm hint: [`sub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) defaults to `$0`, that is, the full record.