# How to speed up reading txt file in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I am buliding a script that reads 24 daily hourly temperature data to extract a latitude-longitude region for a smaller domain. There are three columns in each data file temperature-longitude-latitude and 188426 rows.

```
> ==> 20120810234500.txt <==
> 0.0362,-12.5000,33.5000
> -0.0188,-12.5000,33.5400
> -0.0732,-12.5000,33.5800
> -0.1263,-12.5000,33.6200
> -0.1778,-12.5000,33.6600
> -0.2278,-12.5000,33.7000
> -0.2761,-12.5000,33.7400
> -0.3226,-12.5000,33.7800
> -0.3677,-12.5000,33.8200
> -0.4115,-12.5000,33.8600
```

I have used for and while loops and awk command to read data but it takes a too long time (at least for me) to read, extract and grab the new smaller file. Here you can see the relevant part of the script

```
 # Start 24 hours loop
   lom1=-3
   lom2=3
   lam1=35
   lam2=42

   nhoras=24
   n=1
   while [ $n -le $nhoras ]
   do

    # File name (nom_file) and length (nstation=188426)
     nom_file=`awk -v i=$n 'BEGIN { FS = ","} NR==i { print $1 }' lista_datos.txt`
     nstation=`awk 'END{print NR}' $nom_file`

    # Original data came from windows system and has carriage returns
     dos2unix -q $nom_file

     # Date, time values from file name
     year=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 1-4`
     month=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 5-6`
     day=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 7-8`
     hour=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 9-14`

     # Part of the string to write in the new smaller file
     var1=`echo $nom_file | awk '{print substr($0,1,4) " " substr($0,5,2) " " substr($0,7,2) " " substr($0,9,6)}'`

     # Read rows 65000 to 125000 to gain processing time
     m=65000
     #while [ $m -le $nstation ]  # Bucle extración datos
     while [ $m -le 125000 ]  # Bucle extración datos
     do

        station_id=$m
        elevation=1.5   
        lat=`awk -v i=$m 'BEGIN { FS = ","} NR==i { print $3 }' $nom_file`
        lon=`awk -v i=$m 'BEGIN { FS = ","} NR==i { print $2 }' $nom_file`

    # As lon/lat are floating point I use this workaround to get a smaller region
    lom1=`echo $lon'>'$lon1 | bc -l`
    lom2=`echo $lon'<'$lon2 | bc -l`
    lam1=`echo $lat'>'$lat1 | bc -l`
    lam2=`echo $lat'<'$lat2 | bc -l`

    if [ $lom1 -eq 1 ] && [ $lom2 -eq 1 ];
    then
      if [ $lam1 -eq 1 ] && [ $lam2 -eq 1 ];
      then

       # Second part of the string to write in the new smaller file
         var2=`awk -v i=$m -v e=$elevation 'BEGIN { FS = ","} NR==i { print "'${station_id}' " $3 " " $2 " '${elevation}' 000 " $1 " 000" }' $nom_file`

       # Paste
         paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2") -d ' ' >> out.txt

       fi # final condición lat
     fi # final condición lon

        m=$(( $m + 1 ))

     done # End of extracting loop

     # Save results
     cat cabecera-dp-s.txt out.txt > dp-s$year-$month-$day-$hour

     rm out.txt
     n=$(( $n + 1 ))

   done  # End 24 hours loop
```

By now it takes two hours to process a single imput file. Is there any option to speed up the process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like your are calling `awk` many times while reading the full file. What about doing all of the process in `awk`? I haven't digged into the logic, but if you give an schema, together with a basic sample input / desired output, it will be easier to assist you.

Comment: OR phrase it another way:  all of the times you call awk or cut or any command you create a child process when you assign the result to the output of the command to a variable.  Example: If your code creates, say,  30 child processes per run, and you run it against 3000 files you have to create 90000 child processes. That is a lot of overhead.  You create many more than 30 child processes  per run, it seems.

Comment: That's insane, you are reading the entire file 60,000 times twice (once to get field2 and again to get field 3 from the same line!), fully from start to end for each of hour, i.e. 24 times! The lines starting `lat=...` and `lon=...` are mad!

Comment: Look into the `read` built-in and `bash`'s parameter expansion operators, specifically substring expansion (for example, with `foo=abcde`, `${foo:2:2}` would be the string "cd").

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to read a file line-by-line in `bash`.

Comment: @fedorqui What I am trying is a loop to read 24 files, then for each file I want to read lat and lon (fields 2 and 3) to check if they are in my region of interest. The ones in the region are then output to a file. Output format it is built by pasting var1 and var2 from the script. You can find input file at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lexg0pp42w4hk5x/20120810124500.txt?dl=0 )

Comment: And how do you define region of interest? Because it looks like some `awk -F, '$2>=this_lat && $2<=that_lat && $3>=that_lon && $3<=that_lon' files* > output` would make it. See also [Filter coordinates in a given range](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31290947/1983854) for an example.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell for pointing programming mistakes. I need these two variables to check lat-lon region. Will try to improve.

Comment: Thanks @jimmcnamara I notice I have to improve the script so it does not create so many processes. Any idea on how to fix it? I'm neither bash nor awk expert.

Comment: @chepner An interesting article on read. Now I have to find the way to use it. Will continue investigating. Thanks.

Comment: @fedorqui Your awk sentence for defining region works fine and fast, this will greatly improve the script. I will continue to improve reading this first output to move to the final format. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it may be useful to you to paste the code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ to see some "spelling" errors, as well as recommendations on how to code safely.

Comment: Show your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: @Cyrus Desired output comes from the paste command `paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2") -d ' ' >> out.txt`  Basically I want to move from temp, lon, lat columns to year, month, day, hour, lon, lat, elevation, 000, temp,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments and specially thanks to @fedorqui

With the right use for awk processing speed has dramatically increased. My first attempt processed a single file in 2 hours, now 24 files have been processed in 93 minutes. There should be room for improvement but right now is fine for me. Thanks again.

I attach the script, maybe it could be useful for someone

```
#!/bin/bash

# RUTAS
base=/home/meteo/PROJECTES/TERMED
dades=$base/DADES
files=$base/FILES
msg_data=$dades/MSG/Agosto
treball=$base/TREBALL

# INICIO DEL SCRIPT

cd $treball

rm * 

# Header for final output
cp $files/cabecera-dp-s.txt ./


# Inicio bucle dia
for dia         

in 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

do

   cp $msg_data/$dia/* ./

   ls 2*.txt > lista_datos.txt

   awk '{print substr($0,9,6)}' lista_datos.txt > lista_horas.txt

   nhoras=`awk 'END{print NR}' lista_horas.txt`

   # Inicio bucle hora
   n=1
   while [ $n -le $nhoras ]
   do

    # File name and size
     nom_file=`awk -v i=$n 'BEGIN { FS = ","} NR==i { print $1 }' lista_datos.txt`
     nstation=`awk 'END{print NR}' $nom_file`

    # avoid carriage returns
     dos2unix -q $nom_file

     # Date values
     year=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 1-4`
     month=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 5-6`
     day=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 7-8`
     hour=`echo $nom_file | cut -c 9-14`

     # Extract region, thanks fedorqui       
     awk -F, '$2>=-3 && $2<=3 && $3>=35 && $3<=42' $nom_file > output-$year$month$day$hour.txt

     # Parte 1 de la línea de datos RAMS
     var1=`echo $nom_file | awk '{print substr($0,1,4) " " substr($0,5,2) " " substr($0,7,2) " " substr($0,9,6)}'`

     # station_id, latitud, longitud, elevación y temperatura para cada punto
     m=1
     nstation=`awk 'END{print NR}' output-$year$month$day$hour.txt`

     while [ $m -le $nstation ]  # Bucle extración datos
     do
        station_id=$m
        elevation=1.5   

       # Parte 2 de la línea de datos RAMS
         var2=`awk -v i=$m -v e=$elevation 'BEGIN { FS = ","} NR==i { print "'${station_id}' " $3 " " $2 " '${elevation}' 000 " $1 " 000" }' output-$year$month$day$hour.txt`

       # Pegamos las dos partes para construir la línea de datos 
        paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2") -d ' ' >> out.txt

        m=$(( $m + 1 ))

     done # Final bucle extracción datos

     # Guardamos la salida con el formato y nombre RAMS
     cat cabecera-dp-s.txt out.txt > dp-s$year-$month-$day-$hour

     n=$(( $n + 1 ))

     rm out.txt
   done  # Final bucle horas

   # Borra datos para evitar conflicto con lista_horas, lista_datos
   rm *txt

done            # Final bucle dia
```